# How to Solve issue "Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.evrencoskun.tableview.TableView"

Tags: android, tableview, libraries

I downloaded the tableview jar file library and copy to libs folder in my project and add it to **gradle** from File->Project Structure but there is problem when i add com.evrencoskun.tableview.TableView to xml and error :

Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.evrencoskun.tableview.TableView

```
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.evrencoskun.tableview.TableView
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.evrencoskun.tableview.TableView
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
    at com.example.farzad.table.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/evrencoskun/tableview/R$dimen;
    at com.evrencoskun.tableview.TableView.initialDefaultValues(TableView.java:129)
    at com.evrencoskun.tableview.TableView.<init>(TableView.java:116)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
    at com.example.farzad.table.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.evrencoskun.tableview.R$dimen" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.farzad.table-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.farzad.table-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.farzad.table-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.farzad.table-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.farzad.table-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.farzad.table-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.farzad.table-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.farzad.table-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.farzad.table-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.farzad.table-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.farzad.table-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.farzad.table-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.farzad.table-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
```

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <com.evrencoskun.tableview.TableView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
   </com.evrencoskun.tableview.TableView>
</LinearLayout
```

```
package com.example.farzad.table;
```

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

}

I don't want add this library by :

`compile 'com.evrencoskun.library:tableview:0.8.8'`

because i want to change it and add offline to my projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got this issue, because your added jar did not compile. perhaps you are doing in wrong way.

Instead of telling way to add jar in android studio, i want tell you that if you want edit that library. You can clone it from library github  [page](https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView), and add that downloaded module to your app in Android Studio.